# How to enable HTML minification without breaking images

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, cache, performance

Recently, whenever we try to enable Minifying HTML within the Magento admin panel (Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Template Settings), our product images on the individual product pages fail to load.

A network request just like the one in the screenshot will go out, and immediately fail. Have tried deploying static content and reindexing with no luck.[image: image request]

Anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend html minification as i found that is caused issues with the KO on checkout i have already raised this with Magento as seems to be the same issue across M2.x

Comment: I usually don't minify HTML myself, but was trying to analyze what kind of performance gains we might get from it.

Comment: When i did it i didn't really notice much of a difference i found running the site through cloudflare improved it a little also setup caching on the server also enabling varnish